# Automatizando Inner Join utilizando componente LookupComboBox

Tags: mysql, delphi, join

Algumas vezes eu utilizo o componente TDBLookupCombobox para trazer uma lista de um campo lookup do dataset, essa abordagem agiliza algumas coisas porém é bem limitada.

Por exemplo eu tenho uma lista de lojas em um TDBLookupCombobox e em outro uma lista de clientes, porém os clientes devem aparecer de acordo com a loja escolhida, então existe um componente tipo data ware que automatize isso?

Eu faço isso da maneira tradicional utilizando um inner join de acordo com o a loja escolhida e assim populando o segundo combobox, este sendo do tipo TComboBox.

Comment: Amigo, nesta sua linha de clientes existe um campo que identifique qual a loja ele pertence?

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini sim existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é o seguinte, seguindo o seu exemplo, traga na consulta todos os clientes e todas as lojas, cada um deles em seu `dataset`. Configure ambos lookup's de acordo, agora para fazer o efeito que você quer sem ir novamente fazer uma consulta na base de dados configure o evento `AfterScroll` no `dataset` do cliente para que fique dessa forma:

```
procedure TMeuForm.MeuDatasetClienteAfterScroll(Dataset : TDataset);
begin
  MeuDatasetLoja.Filter := Format('idcliente = %d', [MeuDatasetCliente.FieldByName('idcliente').AsInteger]);
end;
```

dessa forma a cada rolagem no `dataset` do cliente será filtrado o `dataset` da loja.
lembrando que no `dataset` da loja é necessário habilitar a propriedade `filtered := True`.

Comment: no caso, eu quero filtrar os clientes de acordo com a loja, então poderia colocar no evento onExit do DbLookupCombobox esse seu código, que apos eu ter escolhido a loja, ele filtra o dataset de clientes, então dessa forma só aparecerá os clientes respectivos. Porém nessa abordagem eu sempre trago todos os clientes e depois filtro

Comment: queria trazer só os clientes respectivos para não ficar lento a aplicação

Comment: @user21051 você teria basicamente essas duas opções para implementar a funcionalidade, tudo recai sobre a análise de custo. o que é melhor? trazer tudo e tornar o carregamento do formulário mais lento ou a cada modificação ir procurar no banco, eu tomaria a decisão dependendo de vários aspectos. se é uma aplicação cliente servidor e normalmente as estruturas de redes são lentas, eu optaria em carregar tudo de uma vez e depois filtrar local, caso a aplicação fosse local então optaria de carregar sob demanda. então tudo depende do seu cenário. a opção de como executar fica a seu critério.